# Ignore numbering of some tables

Tags: tables, captions, counters

I have a document with two tables. I want my second table to be Table 1 both in List of Tables and caption.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{|l|l|}
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
%\caption{my table}
\end{longtabu}

\begin{longtabu}{|l|l|}
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
\caption{my table}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Resetting the counter does not solve my problem because my content is dynamic and I cannot exclude having a small table inside my first table. And I may want this small table to be numbered. So I just want to tell the compiler to ignore some tables.

Comment: If you're saying "small table", why do you use `longtabu` then (emphasis on **long**)? Instead, just use a plain `tabular` and you won't have this problem?

Comment: The small table will replace my "2" in the first table, for example. And that one can be a tabular, no problem. The outer table is generally long over multiple pages. I can't change that.

Comment: In the `memoir` class you can use `\contcaption` instead of `\caption` and the table number will be the same as the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

A 'dirty' workaround: Use a wrapper environment named `Longtabu` having the same parameters and say `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` in the environment end code, in conjunction with `\caption*{}`, which does not make an entry to the LoT.

**Small drawback**

A better setup would test, if the figure number is already larger than 0, otherwise this could lead to bad counter values ;-)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}




\newenvironment{Longtabu}[2][c]{%

\longtabu[#1]{#2}  
}{\addtocounter{table}{-1}\endlongtabu}


\begin{document}



\begin{Longtabu}{|l|l|}
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
\caption*{my table}
\end{Longtabu}

\begin{longtabu}{|l|l|}
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
\caption{my table}
\end{longtabu}

\begin{longtabu}{|l|l|}
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
\caption{my other table}
\end{longtabu}

\begin{Longtabu}{|l|l|}
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
\caption*{Even another table}
\end{Longtabu}

\end{document}
```